# crash after dialog dismiss in android

Tags: android, dialog

I have the following crash

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=DecorView@62c59a[] not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:473)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:382)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:128)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:727)
at android.app.Dialog.-android_app_Dialog-mthref-0(Dialog.java:167)
at android.app.Dialog$-void__init__android_content_Context_context_int_themeResId_boolean_createContextThemeWrapper_LambdaImpl0.run(Dialog.java)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

can anyone please help and tell me what cause this crash and how to solve it ?

**EDIT**

this is the method that show the dialog

```
public static void showDialogMessage(Activity activity, String title,
            String message, String buttonString, final OnClickListener listener) {

        try {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
                dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_error_message_layout);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);

                TextView titleTV = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
                TextView descriptionTV = (TextView) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.description_textview);
                Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
                Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

                titleTV.setText(title);
                descriptionTV.setText(message);
                okButton.setText(buttonString);
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if (listener != null)
                            listener.onClick(null);
                    }
                });

                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
                        android.R.color.transparent);
                dialog.show();
        } catch (BadTokenException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post some code where you displaying dialog

Comment: Ok I will edit the post

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs when `Activity` gets finished before dialog successfully dismisses. So the Dialog's view is not attached to the `windowManager`.

Add this check before dismissing the Dialog:

```
if (!activity.this.isFinishing() && dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Alternatively you can dismiss your dialog in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` of the activity.

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if ((dialog != null) && dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
    dialog = null;
}
```